# Is the use of ChaosMonkey restricted to AWS?

Tags: resilience-testing

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), ChoasMonkey seems to be restricted to AWS:

> Get Auto Scaling Tools
>
> You can use the new AWS CLI tools:
>
> ```
> $ sudo pip install awscli
> ```

Is it possible to use ChaosMonkey on other platforms as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the standalone ChaosMonkey [README](https://github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey):

> ### Requirements
>
> This version of Chaos Monkey is fully integrated with Spinnaker, the
>   continuous delivery platform that we use at Netflix. You must be
>   managing your apps with Spinnaker to use Chaos Monkey to terminate
>   instances.
>
> Chaos Monkey should work with any backend that Spinnaker supports
>   (AWS, Google Compute Engine, Azure, Kubernetes, Cloud Foundry). It has
>   been tested with AWS, GCE, and Kubernetes.

As said there, you'll find supported Spinnaker platforms on https://www.spinnaker.io

Your quote comes from the quickstart documentation of Symian Army, as for any quickstart it is opinionated to keep things as simple as possible, if you don't match the quickstart environment, you will have to dig deeper in the documentations to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Chaos Monkey` tool, released by Netflix might be restricted to AWS at this time. But the approach is definitely not restricted and can be implemented anywhere where there are distributed systems comprised of a multitude of redundant parts, hopefully with automated healing ability.